# Change my display name without waiting a month

Tags: support

I thought my display name was "Mark Dominus", but it seems to be "004". I don't know how that happened; perhaps I changed it accidentally when I was updating my profile.  Whatever the reason, the profile page says I can't change it again for 30 days.  Meantime, I seem to be stuck with "004".

Is there a way to have an exception made?  Whom would I ask?

Thanks for any help.

ADDED: Please note the large red message in this screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed your display name back to "Mark Dominus"  (note that it may take a while for the change to take effect on your meta account). If there are any further issues the moderators are happy to help.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your display name by clicking Edit in your parent user page.

If not, perhaps moderators will come to rescue.

Are you really 13 years old?

Comment: Yes. He started his blog [when he was six](http://blog.plover.com/2005/10/)!

Comment: A genius is found!

Comment: You can't change your display name more than once per 30 days, according to the message I received. My question is how to circumvent this.